# Tap on rightView of textField when this textField be disabled in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, rightview

I have a textField like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleTextField:UITextField!
```

Then I add image beside this textField:

```
titleTextField.rightView = titleImg
```

with titleImg is a imageView.
I used UITapGestureRecognizer to tap on titleImg imageView, it working fine.

And finally, I set:

```
titleTextField.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

but with this, my titleImg can't be tap. 
It mean I want disable titleTextField, but user can tap on titleImg.
How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your titleImg is added to titleTextField, so on disabling user interaction of text field, it won't allow image view to take tap. You should remove titleImg from titleTextField and use separate UIButton with image added for taking tap while text field is disabled.

Comment: I get your idea, but my UI must be implement like what i say above (rightView). If i have no idea in some day, maybe i change UI that you say!

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: @user12981435 check my answer bro

Answer (score 3):

So I see this question has not had a final solution, therefore I add my solution for this.
You don't need to set `titleTextField.userInteractionEnabled = false`

let it's `true` and set delegate for your `titleTextField` to your ViewController (for example) or any object you consider.

Implement the delegate function `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and `return false` value and it will work.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title IMG is added to the title text field, so disabling user interaction of the text field, it will not allow the image view to be tapped. You should remove titleImg from the title text field and use a separate UIButton with the added picture to take tap when the text field is disabled.

Answer (score -1):

Try enabling `UIImage's` user interaction.

```
titleImg.userInteractionEnabled = true
```